# How to print/show an expression in rational number form in python

Tags: python, math, tkinter

I've been developing a Tkinter app and at some label i need to put formula that should look like a rational number(expression1/expression2, like a numerator and denominator and a bar between them). I did some digging and couldnt find anything related to it. Any suggestions on how this can be done ?

I even couldnt find anything on printing a fraction in a rational number format on the console. I oonly care about the looks and no calculation will be made with it, its just a label

Comment: Low tech: the numerator in one label, the denominator in another, and a thin solid rectangle between the labels. Tweaking fonts and alignment could get it to look nice. Hi tech: find out how to render LaTex or some other math markup in Tkinter.

Comment: @JohnColeman if you post your comment as an answer i will accept it. I just played around with labels, took some time but worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A high-tech solution would be to use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/index.html) in Tkinter. It provides a scaled-down version of `Latex` which it calls [mathtext](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial). This route doesn't look easy but seems to be possible. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22179244/4996248) question for details. If this way seems too involved, a similar but perhaps easier idea would be to use MathML (officially part of HTML5) for the markup. It might be easier to embed in Tkinter.

A comparatively low-tech approach would be to use two labels (with invisible borders) for the numerator and denominator respectively, with a thin rectangle between them. It will take some tweaking, but you should be able to adjust fonts and alignment so that the result looks like a single expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
print('\n\033[4m'+'3' + '\033[0m'+'\n2')
```

`\033[4m` enables underline

`\033[0m` resets it

It will basically display something that looks like (with an underline under the 3):

```
3
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print '%s'%Fraction(1.5)
>>> '3/2'
```

See: https://pymotw.com/2/fractions/

Comment: http://blogs.diariodepernambuco.com.br/espacodaprevidencia/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/img-thing.jpg
This the format i am trying to display, rather than plain one line 3/2